# Convertendo data para formato americano no delphi

Tags: delphi

tenho o seguinte código:

```
procedure Tfrmniver.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var hoje : tdatetime;
dia:Integer;
begin

//Defini a quantidade de dias
dia:=15;

// vamos obter a data de hoje
hoje := date;

// vamos subtrair 5 dias da data de hoje
hoje := IncDay(hoje, dia);

// vamos exibir o resultado
antecendia:=DateToStr(hoje);

//ShowMessage(antecendia);

end;
```

Preciso converter o resultado final que é a variavel antecedencia para o formato americano yyyy/mm/dd pois para usar como consulta no mysql ele tem a data nesse formato americano.

Alguém consegue me ajudar. Ah, já tentei:

```
hoje:=FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd',now);
```

Mas sem sucesso.

Abs

Answer (score 1):

já conseguir resolver, ficou assim:

```
antecedencia:=FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd', hoje);
```

Abs